# The argument type 'UserRepository/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserRepository/*2*/'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In my main.dart I get the following error:
The argument type 'UserRepository/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserRepository/*2*/'

The code is the following:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();

  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();

  runApp(BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: _userRepository)
    ..add(AppStarted()),
  child: Home(userRepository: _userRepository)));
```

}

And the class AuthenticationBloc looks like this:

```
class AuthenticationBloc
extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;

  AuthenticationBloc({@required UserRepository userRepository})
  : assert(userRepository != null),
    _userRepository = userRepository;

  @override
  AuthenticationState get initialState => Uninitialized();
...
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If I'd have to guess, I'd say you have two classes that are named UserRepository.

Comment: Is UserRepository an abstract or concrete class? 

In the BloC example, `UserRepository`is an abstract class so you need to create a concrete class named `UserRepositoryImpl` so you implement its methods. Therefore, your code should be like the follow:

`final UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepositoryImpl();`

Comment: I saw that I imported the userRepository.dart twice in my authentication_bloc.dart... But now I get the following error: Failed assertion: line 12 pos 16: 'userRepository != null': is not true. This is in this part of the code above: assert(userRepository != null)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error when i had two imports like this:

```
import 'package:app/repository.dart';
// In other file
import 'package:app//repository.dart';
```

Because of that second import which has double '/' it was throwing an error.